# How to localize an Object from Wordpress that is accesible to Typescript?

Tags: typescript, wordpress, localization

I am basically localizing a page_id. It sends the object in JS and so it's not available in Typescript. Allow me to share the code so you will understand better. It works but it compiles with errors.

Register, enqueue, localize.

```
    wp_register_script(         
        'cookies-js',
        get_template_directory_uri(  ) . '/js/cookies.min.js',
        array(),
        '0.1.0', 
        true
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'cookies-js', 'cookieObject',
    array('page_id'   => get_the_ID(  ))); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cookies-js');
```

From Typescript.

```
    if(cookieObject){
        console.log(cookieObject.page_id);
    }
```

With error.

```
     TS2304: Cannot find name 'cookieObject'.
```

It does make sense since I am localizing to JS and NOT typescript. I can't find any workarounds unfortunately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`const cookieObject = (window as any).cookieObject;`

Adding this line in the top of the Typescript script solves it. However they are people online that are discouraging the use of this method.

https://dev.to/zapkub/stop-using-window-as-any-41i1